# How to show checkboxes as checked when values are set in the database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm setting up entrust and trying to manage roles via an edit users page. I have pulled the list of available roles as well as the roles that the user is already assigned to and have them passed to the view as `$roles` and `$assignedRoles`.

The problem I'm having is getting the form to show the already assigned roles (`$assignedRoles`) as checked and the un-assigned roles (remainder of `$roles`) as not checked.

$roles looks like

```
    [{"id":1,"name":"Admin","created_at":"2014-09-15 14:26:24","updated_at":"2014-09-15 14:26:24"},{"id":2,"name":"Pastor","created_at":"2014-09-15 14:26:34","updated_at":"2014-09-15 14:26:34"},{"id":3,"name":"Elder","created_at":"2014-09-15 14:26:43","updated_at":"2014-09-15 14:26:43"},{"id":4,"name":"Ministry Leader","created_at":"2014-09-15 14:26:55","updated_at":"2014-09-15 14:26:55"}]
```

and $userRoles looks like

```
    [{"id":1,"name":"Admin","created_at":"2014-09-15 14:26:24","updated_at":"2014-09-15 14:26:24","pivot":{"user_id":1,"role_id":1}}]
```

I am iterating through the available roles in the view using

```
@foreach ($roles as $role)
    {{ Form::checkbox('role[]', $role->id) }}
    {{ Form::label('role', $role->name) }}<br>
@endforeach
```

My problem is that I do not know how I can make it so that when viewing the form it will show which roles are already set as per $userRoles (above).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you make an array with all data

```
<?php 
$all_data = array();
foreach($roles as $role){
     $all_data[] =  $role->id;
}
?>
```

Now you create checkbox

```
@foreach ($roles as $role)
    {{ Form::checkbox('role[]', $role->id, in_array($role->id, $all_data)) }}
    {{ Form::label('role', $role->name) }}<br>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Had to make a slight ammendment, instead of using $roles in the foreach I used $userRoles and it is working perfectly, thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

**In Controller**

```
    $user = User::find($id);
    $allRoles = Role::all();
    $assignedRoles  = $user->roles->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

**In View**

```
<div class="form-group row" id="assign_hostel_fees">
   <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Select Roles</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
          @foreach($allRoles as $role)
             <div class="form-check">
                 <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="{{$role->id}}" {{in_array($role->id,$assignedRoles)?'checked':''}}>
                    {{$role->name}}
                 </label>
             </div>
          @endforeach
       </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this might help you -

```
{{ Form::checkbox('agree', 1, true) }}
```

will generate -

```
<input checked="checked" name="agree" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

the third parameter defines if it will be checked or not. depending on the data(check the role id of `$userRoles` with `$roles`) generate a variable with `true` or `false` value.